# Spring MVC updating an object via form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am currently sending a logged in `User` object to view which will be injected into a form via th:object. I want to update certain attributes in this `User` object but still maintain the rest of the object's content. However, when I submit this form, the `User` object contains null values for all values except the one I have set in the thymeleaf page. I know one solution would be to add hidden tags for the values I want to keep but that seems very tedious if the `User` object is huge.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newprofile", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String newProfile(Model model, Principal principal) {
    String email = principal.getName();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(email);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "newprofile";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/newprofile", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerNewProfile(Model model,User user, Principal principal) {
    userService.saveProfile(user); //this user object will contain null values
    return "redirect:/profile";
}
```

Here is how the form looks. The user object that comes in is an existing `User` with its values already set. There are member variables that can be updated.

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/newprofile}" th:object="${user}" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Registration Form</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{profile.basicInfo.age}" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Update profile</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Once the form is submitted, I perform a save of that User object via Spring JPA's `save()` method. However, if the User object contains nulls, it will incorrectly "update" those values to null. Again, I can do some checking to validate which members should be updated and which should not but that seems incorrect...

```
@Override
public User saveProfile(User user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    userRepository.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [bean validation API](https://beanvalidation.org/) annotations on model class attributes like below:

```
@NotNull(message = "Name cannot not be null")
private String name;
```

Similar use of [`@NotEmpty`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty.html), [`@NotBlank`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html)

By this, it won't enter if any of the validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

If copying the existing User bean before update is an option, following api may be used.

BeanUtils.[copyProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-)

Please do note that there are two popular BeanUtils.copyProperties. One from [Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) and the other one mentioned with this post. The order of method parameters for both these api are different.