# REST API JPA Update only a subset of fields with crud save

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i'm trying to update on the object(using save operation) only the field that is sended on the rest request without having to do a **set** of each field that on the request. I thinked that the @DynamicUpdate help me with that but it only improve the database query to update only the changable fields. As expected only sending the fews fields to update the fields not sended will be set to null. Anyone know an way to do it without the all the check if the fields are in the request and do the set? 
 Where is my code:

Request to change the email of user 1.

```
      "id": 1,
      "email": "test@gmail.com"
  }
```

Update User method from Service:

```
    public User updateUser(User user) throws UserServiceException {

        if (user.getFirstName() != null && user.getFirstName().length() == 0)
            throw new BadRequestException("First Name not valid");

        if (user.getLastName() != null && user.getLastName().length() == 0)
            throw new BadRequestException("Last Name not valid");

        if (user.getCity() != null && user.getCity().length() == 0)
            throw new BadRequestException("City not valid");
        if (user.getEmail() != null && !isValidEmailAddress(user.getEmail()))
            throw new BadRequestException("Email not valid");

        if (user.getPassword() != null) {
            if (!isValidPassword(user.getPassword())) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Password not valid");
            } else {
                bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
                user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            }
        }
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Very thanks!!

Comment: for context purposes: are you using `@Transactional` at method/class level on your UserService class?

Comment: will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59924159/4214241) help ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not copy it well. Yes i am using the @Transactional